# Does `less`'s text search NOT work with huge files?

Tags: less

Either this is a bug, or I'm not understanding something. But I use `less -p value filename.txt` to search for `value` in `filename.text` and when I do it for a file that only contains a couple of lines of text, it finds it promptly and then highlights the result.

However, I'm also using `less` to search in a 73GB file. I'm confident the search result is in the file, still, `less` stops searching at a random location but doesn't highlight its result. Actually, upon closer inspection of that frame, the text string is nowhere to be found either.

Is this expected behavior of less or what is going on here?

I'm able to exclude running out of memory as a cause, I measured memory using `ps aux` and checking the process' proc file but for `ps aux` it was `0.0` percent and `VimSize` was `18432 kB`

Comment: `I'm also using **less** to search in a 73GB file`. Dear God, why? Use something like grep or something. But, to answer your question, check how much memory `less` is using-- I know that less doesn't pull the entire file into memory, but using it to search for a phrase might use more.

Comment: My problem is that I have a huge JSON formatted file with some syntactical errors. And I'd like to find those and edit them out. I don't see how grep can be helpful as the amount of work needed to construct fitting regex patterns is costly when all that would be necessary was to go to that line with a text editor and make changes. Hence I'm using less. Open to alternative approaches too.

Comment: Does this file have newlines, or is it a single line (or very few lines?). Something like `tidy -json` or `json_xs` or `json_pp` could break it into shorter lines with would help both `less` and `grep`. Also, if your search strings are fixed, you can use `fgrep` which is faster. Also, when you do find the errors, how do you plan to edit the file?

Comment: Just to report on memory quickly, I used `ps aux` and before I fed less with a search string for the big file. `px aux` reported no memory use `0.0`. `vmSize` in the proc file of the process was 18432 kB.

Comment: Since you're the OP, put results of commands in your main message.

Comment: If you're really curious, try running it under `strace` to see where it crashes-- I'm guessing it's doing a lot of `lseek`ing and perhaps even `malloc`ing (although your measure of its memory size remaining stable as it runs sort of rules that out)

Comment: I found the question you asked a few comments up interesting: Namely how I'd edit the files had I found the parse error: And this is the key question. I know where the error occurs and I theoretically could manually construct an `sed` or `awk` script. But I'll have to fix the file in many places and escaping and matching json is a ton of work such that I believe a text editor that supported large file editing would truly be the solution here. Does this exist?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138532/discussion-between-barry-carter-and-tim-daubenschutz).